# About Cauchy–Schwarz inequality

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vectors, normed-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

For the vectors $x$ and $y$, the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality reads
$$
|x\cdot y|\leq||x||\cdot||y||
$$
Does this inequality only hold for 2-norm? Or for any norms?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In any inner product space $|\langle x, y \rangle| \leqslant \|x\|\|y\|$.

Comment: @luka5z -- Different inner-product spaces will yield different inner products. The question is this: Suppose a norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies $\sum_i x_i y_i\leq ||x||\cdot ||y||$ for all $x,y$. Must it be the Euclidean norm?

Comment: @uniquesolution -- perhaps I am missing something but since `\mathcal{R}^n` is finite dimensional, norms are equivalent. Now, since the inequality is satisfied by Euclidean norm, it should also hold for other norms?

Comment: I suppose you are missing something, because if you take the max-norm for instance and $x=y=(1,1,...,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then the inner product is $n$, but the product of the norms is $1$.

Comment: @uniquesolution Max-norm doesnt come from any inner product...... Your example is irrelevant. A norm induced by inner product is defined as $\|x\|:=\sqrt{<x,x>}$. The inequality $|\langle x, y \rangle| \leqslant \|x\|\|y\|$ always holds in any inner product (and thus normed) space.

Comment: @luka5z -- I believe we are not reading the same question, and that's the source of confusion. I understand the question as asking whether one can replace the Euclidean norm by any other norm and still have the inequality. How do you understand the question? Also, you are wrong in saying that the inequality holds in any normed space.

Comment: Will the user please clarify their question, as there seems to be some confusion going on.

Comment: @uniquesolution I said any inner space, not normed. Any inner space induces normed space (but not the other way around). I agree, user could have formulated his/her question more precisely. There is serious notational problem in his question too. What $\cdot$ means on LHS and what on RHS?

Comment: You said "and thus normed", did you not?  The l.h.s is $|x\cdot y|$.

Comment: I did. But it does mean that the CS holds for any norm that is induced by inner product (in which case $\|x\|:=\sqrt{<x,x>}$). It does not mean it holds for any normed space, since there are norms which are not induced by any inner product, ok? You are confusing things. Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Comment: @luka5z  Thank you for the wikipedia reference to CS inequality.

Answer (score 2):

With finite sequences $x_i$ and $y_i$, $1\le i\le N$ (assumed positive, or add absolute values  to the  $x_i$s and $y_i$s) you have a generalized Rogers-Hölder's inequality: for $u,v, w>0$ and $1/u+1/v\le 1/w$:

$$\Big(\sum_1^N (x_i y_i)^w\Big)^\frac{1}{w} \le \Big(\sum_1^N (x_i )^u\Big)^\frac{1}{u}  \Big(\sum_1^N (y_i )^v\Big)^\frac{1}{v} $$

See for instance P. S. Bullen, [Handbook of Means and Their Inequalities](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781402015229), 2003, p. 188. I called them Rogers-Hölder from L. Maligranda, “[Why Hölder’s inequality should be called Rogers' inequality?](http://mia.ele-math.com/01-05/Why-Holder-s-inequality-should-be-called-Rogers-inequality) ” Math. Inequal. Appl., vol. 1, no. 1, pp. 69–83, 1998.

You recover your case with $w=1$, and the inequality on $u,v,w$ offers you different options.

Answer (score 1):

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is a special case of Hölder's inequality, which reads as follows:
$$\left \vert \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} \right \vert \leq \left \Vert \vec{a} \right\Vert_p \left \Vert \vec{b} \right\Vert_q$$
where $\dfrac1p + \dfrac1q = 1$ and $\Vert \cdot \Vert_s$ is the $s$-norm of the vector.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @uniquesolution Doesn't it answer the question? Instead of $2$ norm, we can choose the $p$ norm for one vector and $q$ norm for another vector such that $1/p+1/q = 1$.

Comment: No, you can't because the OP asks you whether there is a norm -- one norm -- that you can put on the r.h.s of the inequality while the l.h.s of the inequality remains as it is, with the natural inner product.

Comment: @uniquesolution The OP says "Or for any norms?"

Comment: It is pretty obvious to me he or she do not mean different norms on the r.h.s, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @uniquesolution OK. In which case, could you remove your down vote? Thanks.

Comment: Until proven otherwise, I just don't think you are answering the question at all, sorry.

Comment: @uniquesolution Your logic is flawed. Proven otherwise is decided by the OP not by someone else.

Comment: I believe the question is much more interesting than rendering it trivial by quoting Holder's inequality. It actually asks you to prove or disprove the following: "Let $ ||\cdot|| $ be a norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the following inequality (the OP's inequality) holds for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Must $||\cdot||$ be the Euclidean norm?" That is what I believe to be the question, and your answer is nowhere near.